# In tar how can I exclude dir contents but leave empty dir

Tags: linux, bash, tar

I want to create a tar file excluding certains folders who have many sub-folders and files, but leaving only the main folders that's being excluded. Explaining:

```
-project
  |-dir1
  |-dir2
  |-cache
  |-logs
  |-dir3
  --dir4
```

I want my tar to exclude cache and logs content (files and folders) but mantain this empty folders in the tar file.

if I use --exclude=project/cache it excludes the folders from the file.
How Can I do this ?

Comment: How about `--exclude=project/cache/*`?

Comment: well I really though I tried that. It worked. Thanks. If you want, put it as an answer so I can accept and you gain credit for it.

Comment: This will not exclude dot files inside the cache folder, I believe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can exclude the files in the directories in question without excluding the directories themselves with `--exclude=project/cache/*`.

Be mindful that if there are dotfiles in those directories, they will still get picked up in the tar; if that's the case, you may need to work on a more sophisticated regexp.

Comment: +1 for mentioning about hidden files (dotfiles).

Answer (score 1):

Minor improvement to @MadHatter's answer to also prevent dotfiles:

`--exclude=project/cache/{*,.*}`